# Filter groups that have a difference more than a specific value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I actually want to group by v1, and filter only those that the difference between min(v3) and max(v3) is bigger than 6
I have the following data frame

```r
v1  v2  v3
a   2   13
b   5   3
c   2   1
d   2   1
e   1   2
a   2   4
a   8   1
e   1   9
b   0   1
c   2   8
d   1   5
```

If we calculate we will find :

```
a   “13-1”  =12
b   “3-1”   =2
c   “8-1”   =7
d   “5-1”   =4
e   “9-2”   =7
```

So the expected result would be keeping values of groups a, c and e as they are all >=6

```r
v1  v2  v3
a   2   13
c   2   1
e   1   2
a   2   4
a   8   1
e   1   9
c   2   8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `group_by` `v1` and use `diff` on `range` of `v3` values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(v1) %>% filter(diff(range(v3)) >= 6)

#  v1       v2    v3
#  <fct> <int> <int>
#1 a         2    13
#2 c         2     1
#3 e         1     2
#4 a         2     4
#5 a         8     1
#6 e         1     9
#7 c         2     8
```

OR we can also use `max` - `min`

```
df %>%  group_by(v1) %>%  filter(max(v3) - min(v3) >= 6)
```

---

We can use the same in base R `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(v3, v1, FUN = function(x) diff(range(x))) >= 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr` to group by 'v1' and get the `diff`erence of `range` of 'v3' to be less than 6

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(v1)%>%
  filter(abs(diff(range(v3))) >= 6)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   v1 [3]
#  v1       v2    v3
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 a         2    13
#2 c         2     1
#3 e         1     2
#4 a         2     4
#5 a         8     1
#6 e         1     9
#7 c         2     8
```

Or we can `arrange` the column 'v3' and then `filter` by the difference of `first` and `last` values

```
df1 %>% 
    arrange(v1, v3) %>% 
    group_by(v1) %>% 
    filter(last(v3)  - first(v3) >=6)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[abs(diff(range(v3))) >= 6], by = v1]
```

Or another option is `.I`

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[abs(diff(range(v3))) >= 6], by = v1]$V1]
```

---

Or another option is `ave` from `base R`

```
i1 <- with(df1, ave(v3, v1, FUN = function(x) abs(diff(range(x)))) >= 6)
df1[i1,]
```

Or using `subset` and `tapply`

```
subset(df1, v1 %in% names(which(tapply(v3, v1, 
           function(x) diff(range(x))) >=6)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "e", 
"b", "c", "d"), v2 = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
1L), v3 = c(13L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 5L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: A *data.table* alternative that doesn't require subsetting`.SD` each time would be `dat[, if( abs(diff(range(v3))) > 6) .SD, by=v1]` - I *think* that should be more efficient.